# Wiat for fadeOut to complete its effect then execute fadeIn effect

Tags: jquery

I have these two effects in my script.

```
$("#imgContainer").fadeOut(500);
$("#b").fadeIn(500);
```

I want the wffect of `$("#b").fadeIn(500);` after the first one completes its effects fully. How can i do it.

I have tried this

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    $("#imgContainer").fadeOut(500);
  }, 500);
```

but not worked.

I have also tried this `$("#imgContainer").fadeOut(500).delay(500);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#imgContainer").fadeOut(500,function(){
   $("#b").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `callback function`,

```
$("#imgContainer").fadeOut(500,function(){ $("#b").fadeIn(500); });
```